# aws-lambda handler with InputStream com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.io.InputStream

Tags: serialization, aws-lambda, jackson, aws-api-gateway

I put my AWS Lambda behind API gateway, and now trying to make an end-to-end call.

```
import java.io.InputStream

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.{Context, RequestHandler}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

case class MyClass(a: String, b: String)

class MyHandler extends RequestHandler[InputStream, Boolean] {

  val scalaMapper: databind.ObjectMapper = {
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
    new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
  }

  def handleRequest(input: InputStream, context: Context): Boolean = {
    val myClass = scalaMapper.readValue(input, classOf[MyClass])

    isValid(myClass)
  }
```

It works when I test locally by providing the handler with a string, but when in a Lambda, the handler can't use the input stream. I'm getting the error

```
Endpoint response body before transformations: {
"errorMessage":"An error occurred during JSON parsing",
"errorType":"java.lang.RuntimeException",
"stackTrace":[],
"cause": {
"errorMessage":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Can not construct instance of java.io.InputStream, 
problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n 
at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@2698dc7; line: 1, column: 1]",...
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java Lambda has two possible signatures:

```
public interface RequestHandler<I, O> {
    public O handleRequest(I input, Context context);
}
```

and

```
public interface RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException;
}
```

I'm not sure if you're trying to mix the two but you're trying to tell Lambda to deserialize an `InputStream`.

While I try hard not to do anything in Scala, I believe you want:

```
case class MyClass(a: String, b: String)

class MyHandler extends RequestStreamHandler {

  val scalaMapper: databind.ObjectMapper = {
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
    new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
  }

  def handleRequest(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream context: Context): Unit = {
    val myClass = scalaMapper.readValue(input, classOf[MyClass])

    output.write( isValid(myClass) )
  }
```

Though I have not tested this.  Another, perhaps better way would be:

```
case class MyClass(a: String, b: String)

class MyHandler extends RequestHandler[MyClass, Boolean] {

  def handleRequest(myClass: MyClass, context: Context): Boolean = {   
    isValid(myClass)
  }
```